# python.exe Syntax issue - NPM

Tags: python, npm-install

I am having trouble when running Npm install. I get the following error:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\userxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
```

I have added to my **Path system variable** the following:

```
C:\Python27\
```

In my **user Path variable** I have the following for Python:

```
C:\Users\userxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\userxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
C:\Users\userxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
C:\Users\userxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
```

Not sure what is going on here so any help appreciated!

Comment: I am seeing this problem on a fresh installation of node-js LTS 10.15.3.

Comment: If the offending npm package is node-sass, there is now version 5.0.0 available, which runs on python3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command you are attempting to run uses Python 2 syntax.  It is incompatible with Python 3, so if you try to use that, you *should* get a syntax error.

Either upgrade the script to Python 3 (about time already), or fix the execution path so that it can be run with the obsolescent Python version.

Answer (score 8):

Two solution we can try in this case

1. Downgrade Python to `2.x.`
2. Install the packages using `npm install --ignore-scripts`

   NOTE: This will cause npm to stop running scripts defined in the package.json