# Cannot install packages via yarn in electron project (Python syntax error?)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, yarnpkg, node-gyp

I'm running into an error when trying to install the mitt package in a Quasar / Electron project. I use yarn, but npm runs into the same errors. Perhaps it has to do with me upgrading nodejs recently via the installer on their website instead of via nvm or a similar tool? I'm quite lost at what to do here. Also tried removing node_modules and reinstalling, but same results.

Current node version is 14.15.4.

It looks like [the issue asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338620/python-exe-syntax-issue-npm), where the solution was downgrading Python to a 2.x version. But Python 2.x is now not supported anymore...

The error messages:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6" 
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Git\libra\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Git\libra\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
```

If helpful, here the full log from running yarn install

```
yarn install v1.22.5
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
[3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning "electron-toolkit > bootstrap@4.5.3" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.16.1".
warning " > eslint-loader@2.2.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@>=1.6.0 <7.0.0".
warning " > eslint-loader@2.2.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2.0.0 <5.0.0".
[5/5] Building fresh packages...
[5/5] ⠄ electron
[2/5] ⠄ sqlite3
[3/5] ⠄ node-sass
[-/5] ⠄ waiting...
error D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments:
Directory: D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.11.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp info check checked for "D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 403 https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@14.15.4 (node-v83 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp http 403 status code downloading tarball https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-win32-x64.tar.gz
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
gyp info ok
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.15.4 | win32 | x64
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:308:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\napi-v6-win32-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6" 
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\Git\libra\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Git\libra\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Git\\libra\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Git\libra\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
```

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing python 2.7 and changing path variables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are running windows, and one of the modules you are trying to install is incompatible with it.

`info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.`

Comment: Thanks, but that warning is expected (project targets multiple platforms).

Answer (score 0):

I had a little bit different issue, but similar, always failed whenever add package via `yarn add {packagename}` in macOS catalina (10.15.7). How I resolved is by downgrading and using node 10. Need to install nvm first for easy node version installation anyway. Hope it helps the community when they are faced with the error.